# React - Sorting is being done except first element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting

I was doing React add list and sorting, but the sorting is not working perfectly.
it sort well except the first elements.
when i add aa, bb, cc elements in order, it should sort as cc, bb,aa, but it actually
sort as aa, cc, bb. When i add other elements, it works well except first element 'aa'

[problem screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDyk2.png)

I am working on this for two days but still don't know what's the problem... please help me

My sort function is like this,

```js
handleList = () => {
  const { information } = this.state;
  information.sort((a, b) => (a.name > b.name ? -1 : 1));
  this.setState({
    information: information,
  });
};
```

My state, and handleCreate function

```js
id = 0;
state = {
  sortingState: false,
  information: [],
};
handleCreate = (data) => {
  const { information } = this.state;
  this.setState({
    information: information.concat({ id: this.id++, ...data }),
  });
};
```

render

```js
render() {
  const { information } = this.state;
  return (
    <div>
      <Input onCreate={this.handleCreate} />
      <DataList
        data={information}
        onRemove={this.handleRemove}
        onUpdate={this.handleUpdate}
      />
      <button onClick={this.handleList}>Sort</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-yalow-89e28?file=/src/App.js

Comment: You should create a minimal reproducible example (preferably on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/))

Comment: @hgb123 thanks i just add the codesandbox link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// try this way
information.sort((a,b)=>
  b.name.trim().localeCompare(a.name.trim())
);

// or this way

information.sort((a, b) => (a.name.trim() > b.name.trim() ? -1 : 1));
```

Comment: Would you explain me what's the difference using trim? Does my inputs basically have blanks?

Comment: it's not worked for your first item is because your other item.name has extra space

Comment: `Object {name: "aa", phone: "123", date: ""}
Object {name: " ff", phone: " 123", date: " "}
Object {name: " bb", phone: " 12", date: " "}
Object {name: " dd", phone: " 11", date: " "}`

Comment: you can see the different of `{name:'aa'} with {name: ' bb'}` the ' bb' have extra space. that's why your first item not work

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `handleSubmit` function.  Change the initial value of your state fields to `""` instead of `" "`.  For example:

```
    handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.onCreate(this.state);
    this.setState({
      name: "",
      phone: "",
      date: ""
    });
   };
```

What your code is doing is adding a space to the beginning of your name string.  Then when it sorts, it sorts the items that begin with space after your first item which does not begin with space.

Therefore, this should fix your problem.